# Is it possible to list which ports in a Podman pod is bound to which container?

Tags: podman

I'm creating a podman pod as follows:

```
podman pod create --name MyAwesomePod --publish=80:8080
```

which effectively binds port 80 on the "inside" of my pod to the podman host's port 8080.

I then add containers to the pod using something like

```
podman run --pod MyAwesomePod --name web myWebServerImage
podman run --pod MyAwesomePod --name db mySqlServer
```

It is then possible for me to access the container running the web server on port 80 as intended (using localhost:8080). However, I cannot figure out if there is a way to display that the routing is going to this specific container. Running `podman ps` gives me a list of both my running containers and the PORT column lists 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp on both, which of course cannot be true.

Is this a flaw in Podman or have I misunderstood the way pods work?

I am running rootless Podman 3.2.0.

Answer (score -2):

Containers in one pod share same network namespace:

https://podman.io/getting-started/network#podman-pods

You can do `netstat -ntlp` on a host machine, but that that point only to a `conmon` process and I do not know how to track final process from there:

```
[centos@... ~]$ sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20623/conmon
[centos@... ~]$ ps 20623
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
20623 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/bin/conmon --api-version 1 -s -c 8084f02f601782166aa3345517235cab499680c54276cbd032530ecdaa998469 -u 8084f02f601782166aa3345517235cab499680c54276cbd032530ecdaa998469 -r /usr/bin/runc -b /var/lib/containers/
```

Anyway I'm on bit older Podman here:

```
[centos@2dprot-webserver ~]$ rpm -q podman
podman-1.6.4-29.el7_9.x86_64
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't really assess the question of whether it is possible to list the routing from the host to which specific pod is answering on that very port.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was about container: "a way to display that the routing is going to this specific container" and for that I think that given "Containers in one pod share same network namespace", `podman port --all` correctly shows given port "attached" to both of your containers - as they share same network namespace. Anyway if I'm just missing your point, ignore me. Good luck!

Comment: No worries. The nomenclature is really confusing. Containers, pods, images and what the heck. My question as it states is if there is possible to see which of the containers in the pod respond to which ports on the host. I know they share the same network namespace, but surely Podman must somehow know to redirect its host port 8080 to port 80 on the container running the webserver and not send it to the container running the database server. I may have phrased my question a bit ambiguously.

Comment: FYI 8080 to 80 redirect is done by CNI plug-in "portmap", but no idea on how to use this info to solve your query. I have a great experience with asking in Podman official mailing list - see https://podman.io/community/#mailing-list.